# Xamarin Forms, Is ItemsView<T> Intended to be subclassed

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Using Xamarin Forms I tried subclassing a ItemsView to create a view that does something like a ListView in order to display an observable collection of viewmodels with a template, but relevant members of ItemsView are internal (a.o. the constructor and a vital property TemplatedItems, of type TemplatedItemsList)

Is ItemsView Intended to be subclassed, and if not: is there an alternative way to create such a view?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation the snippet would suggest that, at least technically, it should be subclassed:

```
public abstract class ItemsView<TVisual> : View,    IItemsView<TVisual>
where TVisual : Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject
```

However, the question is why would you want to? Unless you have a very specific reason I would be looking to use the listView where the `TVisual` type would be of `ViewCell`.

More instruction and information on creating ListViews can be found here:

[http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aXamarin.Forms.ListView](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.ListView)

Comment: The use of Listview and ViewCell solve the problem how each item is presented. But I would like to arange the items in a different way: much like a wrap layout but with a ObservabelCollection of viewmodels as  itemssource. The TemplatedItemsList of ItemView<T> would be usefull for that.

Comment: [Continued] You mention it should technically be subclassed but both the constructor and the TemplatedItemsList are internal. Therefor my question: is it meant to be subclassed or should I look for another approach?